Add "future market values" to close reason
Currently one of the close reasons reads:

Questions on current market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic as the answers are changing too frequently to be useful to others.

I suggest amending this to read:

Questions on current or future market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic as the answers are changing too frequently to be useful to others.

Nothing productive ever arises from a discussion about future market values.

I think that's a good idea.

@NickODell: I've created the reason, could you accept?

@Murch It's done.

I also think that's a good idea. I've created a new close reason in line with Greg's suggestion. @Nick could you please deactivate the old one, then activate the new one? I can't approve it myself.
